# Accessing data in HEC-HMS that cannot be exported?

Tags: export, hec-hms

In HEC-HMS 4.8 it is possible to export data via the GIS module. However not all data can be exported, for example the location of sinks or reconditioned terrain data is not available for export.

Is there a way to access and export this kind of data without doing a separate analysis in QGIS/ArcGIS?

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Watershed Modeling System (WMS)", you can read the whole HMS model in it. then I believe all items will be found and located.